# If $X_n$ converges to $X$ almost surely how can we proof that $1/X_n$ will converge to $1/X$ almost surely?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

If $X_n$ converges to $X$ almost surely how can we prove that $\cfrac 1{X_n}$ will converge to $\cfrac 1{X}$ almost surely?

Comment: The limit of the quotient of two functions is the quotient of their limits if the limit in the denominator is not equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check if this result is true. Since $g(t)=1/t$ is continuous a.e., $g(X_{n})$ converges to $g(X)$ a.s.